# PHP and mysql Ignoring the special chracters present in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

a little help on this one, here are its details

```
[Products]
id int
name text
category
color
```

Problem is the values of the color field, sample values are:

- `GOLDRED`
- `GOLD-RED`
- `GOLD/RED`
- `BLUE/GREEN-RED`
- `WHITE GOLD-YELLOW/ORANGE`

I could very much clean the search query such as this sample using a basic function

```
"select * from products where color=".cleanstring($stringval)." limit 1";

function cleanstring($var) {
    $newtext = $var;
    $newtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $newtext);
    $newtext = str_replace(" ", "", $newtext);
    $newtext = strtoupper($newtext);
    return $newtext;    
}
```

The problem is with the content.  It's thousands of records without any form of standard in using a naming convention.

I want to select those records with its values clean similar to my `cleanstring()`.

Example:

```
Query = GOLDRED
```

Can select

- `GOLD-RED`
- `GOLD RED`
- `GOLDRED`
- `GOLD/RED`
- `GOLDRED`

Any solution that you could recommend?  Code is in PHP/MySQL.

Comment: have you tried `LIKE` clause `LIKE '%GOLDRED%'`

Comment: I've tried that, problem with that, is that it can't select those with hypens  and slashes and spaces.

Comment: Not very familiar with the `soundex()` function in mysql, but have you tried it?

Comment: haven't tried soundex(), I've checked soundex, it looks interesting but its a bit different.

Comment: you must hv color list to get the break point in GOLDRED or other word,see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
"select * from products where 1".cleanstring($stringval);

function cleanstring($var) {
$color_list = array('GOLD','RED','GREEN','WHITE');

$sql_where='';
foreach( $color_list AS $v){
    if(strpos($var, $v)!==false){
    $sql_where .=" AND color LIKE '%{$v}%'";
    }

}
return $sql_where;

}
//select * from products where 1 OR color LIKE '%GOLD%' OR color LIKE '%RED%'
```

REMARK:

input: GOLDRED ,

match: GOLD RED,GOLD-RED,GOLD/RED..... GOLD/RED/ABC,RED_GOLDGREEN,

may be after get all data , then make func ranking by match % ,like search engine

Comment: I'll check on this Joe Lee. Joe Lee, just a question, have you checked the code.  There are errors in the $sql_where " AND color LIKE '%{$v}%'";

Comment: JOELEE, thanks for the codes, Its partly correct. The main problem is with the content. The color range is way more complicated than this. some are not even color name. Because of the range of colors and other values, it would be impossible for me supply all the needed for the $color_list array.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, and I am sure has tons of downfalls, but if I did not make any mistakes in php code (don't have machine to try it out), it would do the work:

```
"select * from products where color REGEXP '".cleanstring($stringval)."' limit 1";

function cleanstring($var) {
   $var = preg_replace('![-\/ ]+!', '', $var);
   $strLength = strlen($var);
   $parts = array();
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $strLength; i++) {
     $parts[] = ($i > 0) ? substr($var, 0, $i).'[-/ ]?'.substr($var, $i);
   }
   return "[[:<:]](".implode('|', $parts).")[[:>:]]";    
}
```

It would output something like this:

```
"select * from products where color REGEXP '[[:<:]](G[-/ ]?OLDRED|GO[-/ ]?LDRED|GOL[-/ ]?DRED|GOLD[-/ ]?RED|GOLDR[-/ ]?ED|GOLDRE[-/ ]?D)[[:>:]]' limit 1"
```

which basically breaks your keyword in pieces letter by letter, i.e.

- G OLDRED
- GO LDRED
- GOL DRED
- GOLD RED
- GOLDR ED
- GOLDRE D

and do the "LIKE" statement on them but with smarter word boundaries and instead of just space, it considers "`-`" and "`/`" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably You could make just a MySQL regexp with 'GOLD.?RED' or 'GOLD(-|[[:space:]])?RED' ?

That's an online example I made : http://regexr.com?34mmg